# dijit.form.Select showing blank, but dijit.form.FilteringSelect works

Tags: select, dojo, dijit.form

I'm making a form with a drop down box. When I use dijit.form.Select, there is only one option and it's blank. When I use djiit.form.FilteringSelect, the box works as intended. `records` returns a store of the options. Code follows...

js:

```
        oFetchLookup.drcrType(function(records) {
            console.log(records)
            dijit.byId("drcr_drcrtypeid").store = new Memory({
                idProperty: "id",
                data: records
            });
        });
```

html:

```
<select id="drcr_drcrtypeid" name="drcr_drcrtypeid" 
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" 
    data-dojo-props="intermediateChanges:true, style:'width:220px', tabindex:3">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Select widget has a [`setStore`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_9dijit_form_Select_setStore)(if the link doesn't work properly, navigate to "dijit/form/Select" from the treeview on the left and look for "setStore" in the "Method summary") method. Have you tried using it?
Also have you checked [the dojo tutorials](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/)([especially this one](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/selects_using_stores/))?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your issue, but I had something similar happen. Apparently the font color was white on white. FilteringSelect changes the font color to black automatically, but it needs to be explicitly done in Select.